# Sitecore 8 Insert link to items in bucket

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, buckets

I am using Sitecore 8.1 and Glass mapper ORM. In page editor mode, I have a link field which can be linked to news article page. The folder structure is 
News/News article. News folder is of type Bucket and article is bucketable item.

When I am trying to insert link from other pages to the actual news article I am unable to find search box or expand items under news. Is there any way I can insert link to the news article? Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- In the content editor in the view ribbon you can enable "Buckets". This will make all bucket items visible again (the bucket is expanded and all folders and items can be seen in the tree). This setting is taken into account in the "insert link" window as well.
- Use the search tab in the "insert link" window (normally you should have 3 tabs (link, media items, search). The search tab will let you find the bucketed items as well, but also others - it is not restricted to a bucket.

Edit:
After trying this myself, I noticed that if you edit the link field within the experience editor the search is indeed not provided (not even with the general link with search field). In the content editor the search is present.

A workaround is option1, or use an EditFrame. But I would contact Sitecore Support as well and ask them to add this - I'll do it too.

Edit2 : issue has just been registered as a bug. If you need a fix without waiting for a solution in a future version, you can ask Sitecore Support.

Comment: Thanks! Gatogordo. I am unable to see the Second option in my insert link dialog. No Search tab is present.

Comment: Did you try a "General Link with Search" field?

Comment: Just tried this myself and if you edit the link field within the experience editor the search is indeed not provided. It is the case in the content editor.